# How to add script tag dynamically with custom src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I tried it all window.onload() plugins etc... nothing worked. I need to add a script tag with url that generates its own html and js in a div. please help!

```
var url = "http://static.polldaddy.com/p/0000000.js";

var pdScript =  $('<script/>', {src : url});
$('body').append(pdScript);
```

Comment: It's likely that in addition to the typos you have, you'll be unable to do it this way due to the external script (or sript) using document.write, if it uses document.write.

Comment: This is what I thought. Do you know of any other ways of doing this?

Comment: If it does infact use document.write, then you have no choice but to include it directly in the div you want it to display in.

Comment: Yes but that poll ID needs to come in dynamically. Need to hack this!

Comment: maybe, document.write that script onto the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a start, you're appending `pdCsript` but your variable is called `pdSript`. If you correct that, [it works](http://jsbin.com/AjezECi/1) (barring something you haven't mentioned).